# Oracle not available ora-01034

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

I am trying to create to connect with oracle sqlplus. When I login with:

```
User: sys as sysdba
Pass:
```

It says Connected to an idle instance.

And when I try to create a table, it gives the error

```
ORA-01034: Oracle not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

Why is it not creating the table?

Answer (score 13):

First - and most importantly:

#### Only use the SYS account for DBA work. *Never* use it for "regular" work (e.g. creating tables) - use a dedicated regular user account for that.

Secondly: "*connected to an idle instance*" means Oracle was not started. So as you are already connected as sysdba (again: which you should ***only*** do for DBA tasks) you need to start Oracle using the command

```
startup
```

in SQL*Plus.

Then log off, log in with a regular user and create your table.

For details see the manual:

- [Startup Command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve045.htm#i2699631)
- [Administrator's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/start001.htm)

Comment: I don't have any other user to login with. I followed your link and 
entered the command startup mount, the instance was started and database was mounted. But I cannot tables there too. 
Therefore I tried to make new user, but it says using command:
create user test123 identified by password;
then it gave the error ora-01109: database not open

Comment: `startup mount` will not make the database available. You need `startup open` or simply `startup` as I have written. And if you don't have a regular user (which I don't believe as the default installation does create some) then create one ***now***.

Comment: Please tell me how do I create the new user

Comment: @user1889200: you really don't like reading manuals, do you? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_8003.htm

Comment: As mentioned above, when I created user it gave the error :
not connected to oracle. There fore I am confused that from where I create new user

Comment: @user1889200: you need to first ***start*** Oracle - the way I have explained (using `startup` or `startup open`) - and you tried to create a table, not a user in the example of your question.

Comment: I did use Startup open , the result came:
...
Database mounted
ora-01092 oracle instance terminated.disconnection forced
ora-00942 table or view does not exist 
process id: 8964
session id: 9 serial number : 3

then I created new user
It said :
ora-03114 not connected to oracle

Comment: This answer light up my problem. Thanks. This is right answer. Please accept it.

Comment: It's worked for me! thanks a lot. Answer can be ticked as approved.