# errer at line 1 ORA-01034 : ORACLE not available

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have this error when I want to execute a query

```
select * from vehicule
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

Comment: Your database isn't running. Are you connected as sysdba (which would have said 'connected to an idle instance') and creating objects in the sys schema? Or were you connected as a normal user and started getting that error in an existing session?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle not available ora-01034](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786346/oracle-not-available-ora-01034)

Comment: @tilley31 I have already created the user and the database. and before I have this error Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory

Comment: @tilley31 I execute startup in sqlplus and after that i didn't find my table how could i restaure my databse

Comment: after startup I get of from sql and it works